# Which is more correct: 'Instilled upon' or 'Instilled within'?

Tags: logic

They are similar enough to generally not cause an issue of clarity in a sentence, but I am curious which of these is more logically sound:

> It was instilled **upon** me at an early age.

or

> It was instilled **within** me at an early age.

Comment: To *instill* is to *put inside* or *put in*. You want to say *within*.

Comment: With Google ngram you can get a sense of what native speakers tend to say:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=instill+in%2Cinstill+within%2Cinstill+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinstill%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstill%20within%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstill%20upon%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Instilled in" or "instilled into".

Comment: Apart from one with no preposition at all, **every** [example sentence in Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instil) uses *in* or *into*. **None** uses *on, upon* or *on to.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 17th edition of the Chicago Manual of Style (p. 286 or section 5.195) says the correct usage is either *in* or *into* and never *with*. I wouldn't use *upon* either. Thus, the correct sentence is

> "It was instilled into [in] me at an early age."

[image: CMS_17th Edition]

Comment: The CMS, by the way, is one of the most if not *the* most accredited grammar authorities.

Answer (score -1):

To me, the first option is definitely more common, but gives *slightly* more of a feeling that something was imposed than "within me". Both are fine IMO.

Comment: Many Q&A sites on the Internet expressly welcome personal opinions as answers, but SE in general (and EL&U in particular) have a more technical bent and require all answers to provide expertise, supported by citation or reference to authority.

Comment: Of all the answers I've got' I've NEVER had one with a citation or reference. I rarely ever see citations or references in answers. I see hundreds of answers where linguists give their own opinions and ideas. Strange.

Comment: Let me rephrase then: SE *encourages* substantiation in answers ;) (PS: I didn't downvote you.)